# How can I add "deg" after all numbers in trig functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjs

I'm using Node.js with the mathjs package. Mathjs uses radians in its trig functions. I want to include a degree mode for a calculator I'm making. How can I add "deg" after every number within any sin/cos/tan function in a string? This way, mathjs will calculate it using degrees instead so it can work.

Example: `5*(2+3)/sin(4+(3-2))` should become `5*(2+3)/sin(4deg+(3deg-2deg))`
However: `5*(2+3)/(4+(3-2))` should not change.

I've looked everywhere: Regular expressions, reddit, google, I've found nothing. The closest I've come is a regular expression that breaks when there are parentheses inside the sin function (`/sin\(.*?\)/`).

Edit: Yes I have looked at the angle configuration example. No, that doesn't solve my problem: It assumes the user is implementing a single value to calculate the sine of, I am trying to calculate full expressions with a degree mode (mathjs.evaluate())

Comment: Matching balanced parentheses is difficult with regular expressions. You should use a recursive-descent parser.

Comment: Yes I have read that. No, I can't replace the functions, I need this to be toggle-able.

Comment: I suppose you don't want "deg" to be added in `sin(atan(5))`?

Comment: But the example already has it toggleable... it's replacing the functions with versions that respect the toggle... Playing with `deg` won't work anyway because you may have arcus functions as well, e.g. `sin(15 + acos(0.5))` should be interpreted as `sin(15deg + acos(0.5))` and not `sin(15deg + acos(0.5deg))`, and instead you would want `acos` to _return_ degrees here. Replacing the functions should allow you to do all that correctly.

Comment: "It assumes the user is implementing a single value to calculate the sine of, I am trying to calculate full expressions with a degree mode (mathjs.evaluate())" - that's not true.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, CherryDT.

Comment: Correct, trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead simply replace the trig function implementations with versions that use degrees...

Look at the [angle configuration example in the MathJS docs](https://mathjs.org/examples/browser/angle_configuration.html.html). You can use the `math.import` function to provide your own function implementations for `sin`, `cos`, etc., and you can refer to the original ones by first saving a reference to them.

Here is the full example from the linked docs as runnable snippet (copyright © 2013-2021 jos de jong):

```js
  let replacements = {}

  // our extended configuration options
  const config = {
    angles: 'deg' // 'rad', 'deg', 'grad'
  }

  // create trigonometric functions replacing the input depending on angle config
  const fns1 = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'sec', 'cot', 'csc']
  fns1.forEach(function(name) {
    const fn = math[name] // the original function

    const fnNumber = function (x) {
      // convert from configured type of angles to radians
      switch (config.angles) {
        case 'deg':
          return fn(x / 360 * 2 * Math.PI)
        case 'grad':
          return fn(x / 400 * 2 * Math.PI)
        default:
          return fn(x)
      }
    }

    // create a typed-function which check the input types
    replacements[name] = math.typed(name, {
      'number': fnNumber,
      'Array | Matrix': function (x) {
        return math.map(x, fnNumber)
      }
    })
  })

  // create trigonometric functions replacing the output depending on angle config
  const fns2 = ['asin', 'acos', 'atan', 'atan2', 'acot', 'acsc', 'asec']
  fns2.forEach(function(name) {
    const fn = math[name] // the original function

    const fnNumber = function (x) {
      const result = fn(x)

      if (typeof result === 'number') {
        // convert to radians to configured type of angles
        switch(config.angles) {
          case 'deg':  return result / 2 / Math.PI * 360
          case 'grad': return result / 2 / Math.PI * 400
          default: return result
        }
      }

      return result
    }

    // create a typed-function which check the input types
    replacements[name] = math.typed(name, {
      'number': fnNumber,
      'Array | Matrix': function (x) {
        return math.map(x, fnNumber)
      }
    })
  })

  // import all replacements into math.js, override existing trigonometric functions
  math.import(replacements, {override: true})

  // pointers to the input elements
  const expression = document.getElementById('expression')
  const evaluate   = document.getElementById('evaluate')
  const result     = document.getElementById('result')
  const angles     = document.getElementById('angles')

  // attach event handlers for select box and button
  angles.onchange = function () {
    config.angles = this.value
    config.angles = this.value
  }
  evaluate.onclick = function () {
    result.innerHTML = math.evaluate(expression.value)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@10.0.2/lib/browser/math.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Angles</th>
    <td>
      <select id="angles">
        <option value="deg">deg</option>
        <option value="grad">grad</option>
        <option value="rad">rad</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Expression</th>
    <td>
      <input id="expression" type="text" value="sin(45)" />
      <input id="evaluate" type="button" value="Evaluate">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Result</th>
    <td id="result"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: To respond to the edit in the question:

> Edit: Yes I have looked at the angle configuration example. No, that doesn't solve my problem: It assumes the user is implementing a single value to calculate the sine of, I am trying to calculate full expressions with a degree mode (mathjs.evaluate())

That's not true. It doesn't assume that. The example uses `math.evaluate` just as you said. It should work exactly as you need it to. The way it works is just that the new, replaced functions refer to the `config.angles` value when deciding as what to interpret the input (or in case of the arcus functions, to what to convert their result before returning it).

Comment: Would it be possible to instead create new functions for the degree versions? For example: sindeg() would be sin() but for degrees.

Comment: Sure, just give them different names (and then you don't need the `override` switch anymore), and you don't need to save the old function instances, you can directly access them from the `math` object, since you never override them. And of course then you'd hardcode the degree mode into them instead of referring to the configuration object the example was using.